# Rails filter by multiple nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested

Using Ruby on Rails 5, let's say I have two models, Image and Color. Each Image has_many colors and each color has_many Images.

Now I try to get images containing red and blue:

```
Image.joins(:colors).where(colors: {name: 'red'}).where(colors: {name: 'blue'})
```

I know there are images containing red and blue, but the line above always returns nil. When I do

```
Image.joins(:colors).where(colors: {name: 'red'}).first.colors
```

it contains blue.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You get no results because based on the definition of your relationships one image can have many colors, so one color is one row in the join table, and you're filtering the rows that match the same columns but with two different values at once, which any query like that would return no results. You might have to tweak your query for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Sebastian Palma already explained in his comment: You do not get any result because a line in a join can either have the color red or blue but not both at a time.

In your example you need you select all lines with a red or blue color, then you need to group these lines by the image again, and then only return images that had at least two colors found.

```
Image
  .select('images.*, COUNT(colors.id)')
  .joins(:colors)
  .where(colors: { name: ['red', 'blue'] })
  .group('images.id')
  .having('COUNT(colors.id) >= 2')
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the select is necessary or can be omitted like in Pascal's answer

Comment: The select is useful because otherwise, the returned images would include color values. And depending on your database engine it might complain when you try to use `HAVING COUNT` without the `COUNT` being included in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes i was wondering if activerecord does it for you if you omit it or not

Comment: .where(colors: { name: ['red', 'blue'] }) returns all images where it's color is red or blue. When I count the color.id's at the end, how can i be sure it contains both, 'red' and 'blue' (and maybe any other color) but not 'green' instead of 'red' or 'blue'?

Comment: You can be sure because you only select records that are red or blue and then count how many are there. Because you only select those two colors it must be exactly those colors when there are 2 records.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method like this to your Image model:

```rb
  def self.only_colors(clrs)
    Image
      .joins(:colors)
      .where(colors: {name: clrs})
      .group("images.id")
      .having("count(*) = ?", clrs.size)
  end
```

(or create a corresponding `scope` )

Assuming two images, one with only blue, one with blue and red, the `join`and `where` will result in this:

```
image name                       |  color
------------------------------------------------------
study in red and blue            | red
study in red and blue            | blue
feeling blue                     | blue
```

by grouping the rows by the `images.id` column and then filter those grouped rows (`having`) by the number of colors you want to match, you will have only those images with both colors.

Because of the where condition you will only join rows that match the color (red *OR* blue). When you apply the *having* clause (which is kind of *where* but for *group by*) with the number of colors, you essentially turn the *OR* into an *AND*